# php mysql "Display event name according to date"

Tags: php, mysql

How to Display Event name from event table according to date.

[image]

[image]

this is my code iwant to the add the script is this code.

```
$sql = "
SELECT `log`.id, (student.id) as ids, student.name,event, student.`year`, student.section, `log`.date_log, `log`.time_log, `log`.ampm, `log`.status_log, section.sec_name 
FROM `log` 
  Inner Join student ON student.cardcode = `log`.stud_id 
  Inner Join section ON section.id = student.section 
order by `log`.id DESC limit $start, $per_page";
```

Comment: By `using the date` you mean `date_log`?

Comment: yes sir using date_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE log AS L 
INNER JOIN event AS E ON L.date_log = E.date
SET L.event = E.event_name
```

## Edit

Based on the PHP coded:

```
$sql = "
SELECT log.id, (student.id) as ids, student.name, student.year, student.section, log.date_log, log.time_log, log.ampm, log.status_log, section.sec_name, event.event_name AS event
FROM log 
    INNER JOIN student ON student.cardcode = log.stud_id 
    INNER JOIN section ON section.id = student.section
    INNER JOIN event ON log.date_log = event.date
ORDER BY log.id DESC limit $start,$per_page";
```

Comment: thank you for all your answers,

Comment: sir I have some problem,because if I edit the value of event_name the event in table log is not change,all i want sir I can edit the event.

Comment: @MartinJeraldBandolonMorada I assumed your question was about MySQL only, because there is no code at all! I suggest you to create another question about your php problem and provide some code.

Comment: Im so sorry sir,this this the code : $sql = "SELECT `log`.id, (student.id) as ids, student.name,event, student.`year`, student.section, `log`.date_log, `log`.time_log, `log`.ampm, `log`.status_log, section.sec_name FROM `log` Inner Join student ON student.cardcode = `log`.stud_id Inner Join section ON section.id = student.section order by `log`.id DESC limit $start,$per_page";
    }

Comment: @MartinJeraldBandolonMorada edited my answer... don't forget to properly format your codes and don't post long codes like these in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

use this sql:

```
UPDATE `log` SET `event` = (SELECT `event_name` FROM `event` WHERE `date` = log.date_log)
```

Comment: thank you all your answer is correct